# Can Maven App Engine archetypes generate jar only?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, web-applications

It looks like all of the AppEngine archetypes use "war" packaging. If possible, I would like to test my web client javascript code without rebuild the "war" file.

I did change pom.xml packaging to "jar" however the gae server won't start.

For example, how to test UI from [this page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/ui_and_code) without restart backend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the project type to jar, you should just run

```
mvn war:exploded
```

which - more or less - copies the webapp to the target folder. If you skip tests it can be very quick.

Comment: Thanks! Now I like Maven more!